# Does this ggplot code with ggrepel cause anyone else's R to crash?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm visualizing some cricket data from ***cricinfo***. I wanted to highlight some players that fulfill certain criteria, however it keeps crashing R studio.

```
#### Libraries ####
library(cricketdata)
library(dplyr)
library(ggrepel)
library(ggplot2)
### Fetching Data ####
menODI <- fetch_cricinfo("ODI", "Men", "Batting", type="career")
#### Creation of New Stat for Batsmen Ranking ####
menODI2 <- menODI %>% 
  mutate(Stat2 = 1- Average  + Hundreds+Fifties/2)
#### Plot ####
menODI2 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Innings, Stat2)) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_text_repel( col="forestgreen",aes(label=ifelse(Average>50 & Runs > 5000,as.character(Player),'')),
    hjust=1.5,vjust=2.6, size=3)+
  ggtitle("Average >50 + Runs > 5000")
```

R Studio tries to produce the plot, but instead Crashes without giving any reason why. It requires restart.

Comment: If you comment out the `geom_text_repel()` does it run?

Comment: Can't reproduce, everything works for me. Check if you have newest R,Rstudio and listed packages versions.

Comment: @Elin It runs fine with geom_text_repel(). Using geom_text_repel() on another similar plot within the same script and it is running fine.

Comment: So you literally tested what I asked.  What I'm suggesting really is that you go line by line and using commenting isolate the one that is causing the crash.

Comment: * typo. It ruins fine WITHOUT the geom_text_repel(). So the issue is with this line and this plot in particular.

Comment: What happens if you pre calculate the ifelse() ... I find sometimes doing complex  stuff inside of ggplot leads to problems.  So make a vector with the labels you want before starting the ggplot and then use it in the geom_text_repel().

Comment: @Elin, Restarted my computer and now it works.
Thank you for your tip. I will keep that in mind for future

Comment: Note that if, as I believe, this is a memory bug, it may appear to work at first then reappear again later. Could you add your `sessionInfo()` too?

Comment: @Hugh what part of the sessionInfo() do you require?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a buffer overflow, observed on the Windows platform, raised as an issue here.

> https://github.com/slowkow/ggrepel/issues/115

A more reliable reprex is given in the thread:

```
# test for bug in ggrepel/ggplot2
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

# sometimes works, usually R crashes
n = 1000L
my.data <- data.frame(x = runif(n), y = runif(n),
                      my.label = c(rep("", n/100 - 1), "abcd"))

# ggplot(my.data, aes(x, y, label = my.label)) +
#  geom_label()

ggplot(my.data, aes(x, y, label = my.label)) +
  geom_label_repel()

# never works, R crashes

n = 10000L
my.data <- data.frame(x = runif(n), y = runif(n),
                      my.label = c(rep("", n/1000 - 1), "abcd"))

# ggplot(my.data, aes(x, y, label = my.label)) +
#  geom_label()

ggplot(my.data, aes(x, y, label = my.label)) +
  geom_label_repel()
```